# Can I put defined robot keywords under Suite SetUp/ Test Setup in Robot Framework

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I am new to coding and robot framework, Could anyone please kindly explain to me if my approach down here is not applicable.

My goal  would like to do a test setup to create a game as prerequisties in order to let all players to join the same game. Otherwise, robot will loop through my keywords and each time will need to create a new game for the next player to join, which is the case I would like to avoid.

However, it seems that Test Setup doesn't allow me to put my own defined robot keywords and throwing errors, could anyone kindly advise?

```
#Create Trading Arena Game
When Create trading arena game name as ${game_name} with status ${status} where start date on ${minutes_to_start} and end date on ${day_to_end} open for vip tiers ${vip_tiers} and user type ${user_type} and trade filter ${instrument_pair} by wallet ${wallet_type} with min trade volume ${min_trade_volume} and leaderboard ${is_with_leaderboard}
When Wait 60000 millisecond
```

```
#Error log
Using local env settings...
==============================================================================
001.Vip Tiers Join Trading Arena Game                                         
==============================================================================
Level 1 user join trading arena game                                  | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword 'Create Trading Arena Game' expected 0 arguments, got 10.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level 2 user join trading arena game                                  | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword 'Create Trading Arena Game' expected 0 arguments, got 10.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level 3 user join trading arena game                                  | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword 'Create Trading Arena Game' expected 0 arguments, got 10.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level 4 user join trading arena game                                  | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword 'Create Trading Arena Game' expected 0 arguments, got 10.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level 5 user join trading arena game                                  | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword 'Create Trading Arena Game' expected 0 arguments, got 10.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level 6 user join trading arena game                                  | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword 'Create Trading Arena Game' expected 0 arguments, got 10.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level 7 user join trading arena game                                  | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword 'Create Trading Arena Game' expected 0 arguments, got 10.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level 8 user join trading arena game                                  | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword 'Create Trading Arena Game' expected 0 arguments, got 10.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level 9 user join trading arena game                                  | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword 'Create Trading Arena Game' expected 0 arguments, got 10.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001.Vip Tiers Join Trading Arena Game                                 | FAIL |
Suite setup failed:
Keyword 'Create Trading Arena Game' expected 0 arguments, got 10.
```

```
*** Settings ***

Resource        ../../../robot_resources/Common.robot
Resource        ../../../robot_resources/Assertion.robot

Test Template   Different vip tiers of user join trading arena game
Test Setup     Create Trading Arena Game
*** Variables ***
${record_number}        1
${user_1}     1
${user_2}     2
${user_3}     3
${user_4}     4
${user_5}     5
${user_5}     6
${user_5}     7
${user_5}     8
${user_5}     9

${game_name}    Test vip tiers level join trading game
${status}       ACTIVE
${minutes_to_start}   1
${day_to_end}     30
${vip_tiers}    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
${user_type}    INDIVIDUAL
${instrument_pair}      BTC,USDT
${wallet_type}          SPOT
${min_trade_volume}     0
${is_with_leaderboard}  true


${status2}       ENDED
${vip_tiers2}    ${EMPTY}
${user_type2}    ${EMPTY}
${instrument_pair2}      ${EMPTY}
${wallet_type2}          ${EMPTY}
${min_trade_volume2}     ${EMPTY}
${is_with_leaderboard2}  ${EMPTY}

*** Test Cases ***
Level 1 user join trading arena game    ${user1}    ${checking}
Level 2 user join trading arena game    ${user2}    ${checking}
Level 3 user join trading arena game    ${user3}    ${checking}
Level 4 user join trading arena game    ${user4}    ${checking}
Level 5 user join trading arena game    ${user5}    ${checking}
Level 6 user join trading arena game    ${user6}    ${checking}
Level 7 user join trading arena game    ${user7}    ${checking}
Level 8 user join trading arena game    ${user8}    ${checking}
Level 9 user join trading arena game    ${user9}    ${checking}

*** Keywords ***
Create Trading Arena Game

    When Create trading arena game name as ${game_name} with status ${status} where start date on ${minutes_to_start} and end date on ${day_to_end} open for vip tiers ${vip_tiers} and user type ${user_type} and trade filter ${instrument_pair} by wallet ${wallet_type} with min trade volume ${min_trade_volume} and leaderboard ${is_with_leaderboard}
    When Wait 60000 millisecond

Different vip tiers of user join trading arena game
    [Arguments]        ${user}  ${checking}

    When Get latest ${record_number} trading arena game records on ${status}
    When Wait 5000 millisecond
    When Get latest ${record_number} trading arena game records with user eligibility on ${status} of ${user}
    When Wait 5000 millisecond

    When Player join latest ${record_number} trading arena game with tiers level ${user}
    When Wait 5000 millisecond
    Then Should actual result "${user_join_trading_arena_game_record}" match expected "${checking}" result
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I believe you would want a `Suite Setup` instead of `Test Setup` which would create the game before **all** test case starts, instead of creating the game before each test case starts

Second,`Suite Setup` allows user defined keyword but you are passing arguments into `Create Trading Arena Game` at `When Create trading arena game name as ${game_name} ...` while the keyword does not accept any arguments. Not sure why you are recusing the keyword under `Create Trading Arena Game`.